# Alert something on enter key if no forms active in the html site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to make a two-in-one solution for keypress event.

If I hit enter, and no form elements are active in my site I'd like to alert `AAA`.
Else submit the active form. How can i do this?

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode==13){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("AAA");
        }
}); // the enter key hitted and alerted AAA
```

But how can i check the form's state? It's a simple mailsender form with 4 fields, 3 input 1 textarea.

By Raj's comment here is the good solution for this:

```
jQuery.fn.fadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) { 
   return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback); 
};

var hotkeys = true;
$(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if((e.keyCode==13) &&(hotkeys == true)){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#boxforfadein").fadeToggle();
    }
});
$("form *").live("focusin", function(){
    hotkeys = false;
    console.log("hotkeys off");
    return hotkeys;
});
$("form *").live("focusout", function(){
    hotkeys = true;
    console.log("hotkeys on");
    return hotkeys;
});
```

Comment: Why do you want this? Wouldn't you just want to submit to form anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus)** and **[focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)** to keep track of whether your form has focus and display the appropriate alert.

There is also **[document.activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.activeElement)** but I am not too sure if all browsers support it